# Height of the first tab is different from other tabs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Just following by example to learn about Bootstrap, created this page so far, you can copy paste it to reproduce the issue.  My question is what have I done wrong that caused the Home navigation link to be higher than the rest of the navigation links?
[image]

Here is the whole page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>              

        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>Test Page Bootstrap 3</h1>
                <p>Watch this page grow as we learn more!</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">More Detail <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> </a> 

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"> <a href="#">Home</li>
                <li> <a href="#">Menu 1</li>
                <li> <a href="#">Menu 2</li>
                <li> <a href="#">Menu 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> 
                <p> Paragraph1..erfjhjhfdjfhdgfd sfdghfsyfgdfd dsfsdf  dsfsdf 
                dsfdsfsdf ysdff7y er7yf73f ef ffs sf.</p> 
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> 
                <p> Paragraph2...Oh dfifuhyf y fdf erf7yf7ds6 
                dfsdfy  efr98y  efr7y cuhf dfiuhf7 y efyef</p> 
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>


            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> 
                <p> Paragraph3...yey efd dsfij 8777 e4r8ef8c7 3434 f87cersjdkh dffff erer  eee</p> 
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> 
                <p> Paragraph4...Test paragrapg1  1233 eff long text lorum spoz</p> 
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: refer this fiddle and make neccessary changes http://jsfiddle.net/xfw8t/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't correctly close the tag `<a href="#">`

The below should fix it:

```
       <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```